# Solving a multivariate equation for asymptotic complexity

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I have a function $f(m, n)$ with time complexity $T(m, n)$ characterized by the recurrence relation

$$\begin{align}
T(m,\ n) &= 2T\bigl(\frac{m}{2}, \frac{n}{2}\bigr) + c_0 \log n + c_1.\\
T(m,\ 1) &= T\bigl(\frac{m}{2}, 1 \bigr) + c_1 \\
T(0,\ n) &= 1 \\
T(m,\ 0) &= 1
\end{align}$$

I can see that for fixed $m$, this is $O(n)$, and for fixed $n$, this is $O(m)$. But I don't see how I can get an expression that characterizes the performance in terms of variable $m$ and $n$.

How can I solve this to find the asymptotic complexity in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: I would try to analyze it for the three cases $n < m$, $n = m$ and $n > m$. Clearly if $n=m$ then they have the same rate of change and it breaks down to $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c_1 \log n + c_1$. See how it works for the other two cases as well. You can also assume $n$ and $m$ are powers of 2 if that makes it easier.

Comment: What is the significance of those three cases? That seems somewhat arbitrary - I might as well analyze the cases $n < 2m$ or $n < m^2$.
I don't see how checking these regions of the domain will help - I already have the recurrence relation.

Comment: Since they're both decreasing at the same rate (namely $x/2$) the one which is _greater_ will determine how many times the function recurses. If you can determine that, you can get out a summation bounded by how many times the function recurses.

Comment: What are the base cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for simplicity that $m=2^a$, $n = 2^b$, $c_0=1$, $c_1=0$, and the base cases are $T(1,\cdot) = T(\cdot,1) = 0$. Then
$$
T(2^a,2^b) = 2T(2^{a-1},2^{b-1}) + b = 4T(2^{a-2},2^{b-2}) + b + 2(b-1) = \cdots
$$
The number of summands is $c = \min(a,b)$, and using this notation we obtain
\begin{align}
T(2^a,2^b) &= b + 2(b-1) + 4(b-2) + \cdots + 2^{c-1}(b-c+1) \\ &=
(1+2+\cdots+2^{c-1})b - 2^1 (1) - 2^2 (2) - \cdots - 2^{c-1} (c-1) \\ &=
(2^c-1)b - 2^c c + 2(2^c-1) \\ &=
2^c(b+2-c) - (b + 2).
\end{align}
In other words,
$$
T(2^a,2^b) =
\begin{cases}
2^{b+1} - (b+2) & \text{if } a \geq b, \\
(b+2)(2^a-1) - a2^a & \text{if } b \geq a.
\end{cases}
$$
When $m \geq n$, this gives $T(m,n) = \Theta(n)$, and when $n > m$, we get $T(m,n) = \Theta(m\log (n/m)+m)$.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that $c_1 = 0$ ? Why?

Comment: Since $\log n + 1 = \Theta(\log n)$.

Comment: I seem to have missed a case - $T(m,\ 1) = T\bigl(\frac{m}{2}, 1 \bigr) + c_1$.
I've updated my question to show the base cases.
Following your derivation, I get
$T(2^a, 2^b) = 2^{b+1} - 2(b + 1) + a$ in the region where $a >= b$.
Does this still give $T(m, n) = \Theta(n)$ ?


I don't follow how you got from
$T(2^a, 2^b) = 2^{b+1} - (b + 2)$ to $T(m, n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: Oh, I see.
$2^{b+1} - (b + 2) = 2 n - (log(n) + 2)$, which is $\Theta(n)$.
So considering my missed case,
$2^{b+1} - 2(b + 1) + a = 2n - 2(log(n) + 1) + log(m)$.

So that should be $\Theta(n + log(m))$?

Comment: You changed the question. I'll let you work out the updated answer on your own.